# How can I pass props from the current component to another component when the second component is called by url?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, react-state

We can send data as props from parent component to child component easily but what to do in case of no relationship between two components ?

**Please Read my context first so that I can make you understand my problem easily.**

In my e commerce react App, when any new user visits my site I want to recommend the user to register. In registration process I keep two steps.

1. At first I want to take his mobile number from only one input field. when he fills the field and press 'continue' button -
2. I want to take him another page (component) where from I can take his name, password etc.

Here these two components are independent to each other. When user hits the 'continue' button I am calling a  and redirect him to another component.

Now my question is **How do I preserve this mobile number in 1st component and send to the 2nd component**

[N.B: I don't want the mobile number be visible in the url when calling the 2nd Route]

**First Component**

```
export default class FirstComponent extends Component {
    render() {        
        return (
            <div>                
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type Mobile number" />
                <Link to={{ pathname: '/signup' }}>
                    <button>Continue</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Second Component**

```
export default class SecondComponent extends Component {
    render() {        
        return (
            <div>       
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type Mobile number" />

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Router**

```
<Route exact path="/signup" render={(props) => {return <SecondComponent />} }/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/signup', state: { number: 3199192910} }}>
                    <button>Continue</button>
                </Link>
```

And you can access that in your signup component like:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

 class SecondComponent extends Component {
    render() { 
      // get the number 
      console.log(this.props.location.state.number)

        return (
            <div>       
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type Mobile number" />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(SecondComponent);
```

Check out this example, `Quotes` is what you should be looking at:

[image: Edit reverent-swartz-044s2]

Comment: And what do I need to do if I have a functional component instead of class? :)

Answer (score 1):

On click of button, you can call `handleClick` function and inside this function you could use `push` method to send props. This way you would have more control over what representation you want to send your data to other component.

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>continue</button>

handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/signup',
      state: { mobile: this.state.mobileNumber }
    })
}
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 1):

**This is where Redux comes into the picture.**   


Redux is an open-source JavaScript library for managing application state.


 So what happens in redux we having something called store which manages the whole state of the application.
 we dispatch some actions to the stores which calls a function called reducer which mutate the data in the store based on the action that has been dispatched. don't worry if you didn't understand what I said

just watch this 15 min video and you'll completely understand how to use Redux in your application and solve your problem 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX3KeP7v7Kg

 
 in order to learn in depth I will recommend you go through the 
https://redux.js.org/basics/basic-tutorial

now coming back to your problem all you have to do is create a store which saves phone no and when the user clicks on continue button dispatch an action to the reduces to store the phone no and thus your phone no is persisted throughout the application and whenever you want to access the phone just write mapstatetoprops function which is shown in the video to access the data from the store  and use it in that component

Hopefully, this will solve your problem

what happens when you don't use redux
of course, you send data as props but what will happen to the props when you refresh the page!!!! **the props are lost**  but when we use redux we can save the data. And you're application works as expected even after refreshed of course they are many other ways to do it

Comment: I appreciate your nice explanation. Actually I am not wanting to connect my mini component to redux store. My current redux store is a bit weighted. I am afraid about the performance if I connect such a little component to redux store.